# How to extract the contour of a material (2D drawing) with the image processing library opencv and python language?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

- link: [technical  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKys2.jpg)
- The picture shows a technical drawing of a material. I have to contour this material with opencv python. The lines with a large thickness are the lines of the material. But if 3 small lines (indicating length, diameter) join, there is a material line and this is my problem. 
  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Thank you ı changed title. okay?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing something like this.

```
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

You can increase the canny thresholds to only have thick edges.

```
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 300)
```